# Changing Label with Tkinter while canvas/widget is open

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, label

I would like to change the value of label while the widget is open, so I actually see it change after some time.
I've been trying to use time.sleep but the first label won't show. And yeah I know that's because once the program runs the mainloop only takes the last value. Is it somehow possible to show me the first value and then wait 5 seconds and after that the label changes to something else. I've been searching for a solution. I didn't figure it out yet.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `root.after`.

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
label = Label(root, text="this message will self-destruct in three seconds")
label.pack()

def bang():
    label.config(text="this message has self-destructed.")

root.after(3000, bang)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I already found something like this, but I didn't implement it correctly I guess.